# Early stopping criteria when training neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization, validation

What happens if the early stopping criteria suggest to stop training at a very early stage (i.e. after 10 epochs or so). Is it an indicator that more regularization should be applied to the model (I am already using L2 and dropout)? Or maybe the model is overly complex for the specific task I am trying to solve?

Here is how the validation cost per epoch looks like (evaluated on the whole validation set)

[image]

--------------------------------------EDITED--------------------------------------------------

I believe that 10 epochs is a low stage for stoping training since the training accuracy function looks like the picture below. And I know, from previous research, that it is possible to achieve test accuracies of about 70%

[image]

--------------------------------------- EDITED 2 -----------------------------------------------

The training cost decreases steadily (the color of the line changed but it is the same run). Size of minibatch = 256.

[image]

Comment: what makes you think that 10 epochs is particularly early?

Comment: @galoosh33 The fact that the training accuracy at that number of epochs is still low (around 50%), and that it is a solvable task.

Comment: Is your training cost reducing steadily (like the accuracy) or does it have heavy fluctuations like the validation cost?

Comment: are you ensuring you turn off dropout when you test on the dev set?

Comment: @Djib2011 Check the updated post. It does decrease steadily yes.

Comment: @HughPerkins yes I am

Comment: You should note that your validation set cost is only an indication of the performance of your network. The minibatch where you scored the best may have had really easy cases where your model predicted most of them right. That doesn't mean that your model at that instance was the best. Maybe your model isn't doing as bad as you think. I've had instances where the validation cost raises steadily, while the metric I actually want improves steadily. This happens to me mostly in imbalanced tasks, where I use class weights (not sure if that has anything to do with it).

Comment: @Djib2011 That is true. I will start to look at the validation accuracy and see how that behaves. I don't use any class weights, but I do have imbalanced number of examples across classes. Good comment, thanks

Comment: Wait, is this over minibatches? you should be summing the validation loss over entire epochs.

Comment: @HughPerkins The first plot (validation cost) is performed over epochs, i.e. evaluating the whole validation set